# How do I show two different object types in UIPickerView for two different components?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uipickerview

I have a picker with two components. In component 0 (kCardComponent) I want NSStrings to appear. In component 1 (kSuitComponent) I want UIView. Here is the code from my picker view. The program crashes, I'm assuming because it's returning an NSString when it should be returning a UIView in this method

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
        viewForRow:(NSInteger)row
      forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
if (component == kSuitComponent) {
    UIImage *image = self.suitImages[row];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    return imageView;
}
else
    return (UIView*)self.cardNumber[row];
}
```

I've tried creating another picker view -(NSString*)pickerView, but that did not work. What should I do?

Comment: didn't get you exactly.. please   explain your question in detail .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't return strings from this delegate method, only views. Since you need a view for one component, you need a view for all. What you need to do is create a `UILabel` and set its text to the string you have.

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
    if (component == kSuitComponent) {
        UIImage *image = self.suitImages[row];
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        return imageView;
    } else {
        NSString *text = self.cardNumber[row];
        UILabel *label = ... // create label
        label.text = text;
        return label;
    }
}
```